# LVM - Relocating ./home ./var ./srv to the same partition

Tags: linux, centos, lvm, volume

I use CentOS-8 as virtualisation host (so I would like to avoid installing too many apps)
1x Drive,
LVM filesystem

With a fresh install; I created `./boot`, `./boot/efi`, `./home`, and `./`

Each on its own partition.

Which tool and commands do I need to relocate `/var`, `/tmp`, and `/srv` to the partition containing `/home`?

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to do this by copying those directories under `/home` (using `mv`) and creating symlinks (using `ln -s`), it's not a good idea.

Symlinking top-level directories that aren't intended to be symlinks tends to result in hard-to-debug problems since many applications aren't expecting this behavior.  For example, if an application uses `O_NOFOLLOW` for security reasons when opening a file, then that application will fail to work when symlinks are created.  I've seen multiple situations where this occurs, and distro maintainers (not to mention software authors) are generally unsympathetic to problems occurring in this scenario since it's not supported.

In general, it would be better to either have `/`, `/home`, `/var`, `/tmp`, and `/srv` on one partition and make it expandable by using LVM, or create separate partitions for the things you need separate.

If you're using LVM already and you want to create additional logical volumes as part of the same volume group you're already using, you can find the volume group with `sudo vgdisplay -c | cut -b3- | cut -d: -f1` and then create additional logical volumes like so:

```
SIZE=100m # for example
DIRNAME=/srv # for example
VOLGROUP=$(sudo vgdisplay -c | cut -b3- | cut -d: -f1)
sudo lvcreate -L $SIZE -n $(basename "$DIRNAME") $VOLGROUP
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/$VOLGROUP-$(basename "$DIRNAME")
sudo mount /dev/mapper/$VOLGROUP-$(basename "$DIRNAME") /mnt
sudo cp -a $DIRNAME/* $DIRNAME/.* /mnt
sudo umount /mnt
# Add the new /dev/mapper/$VOLGROUP-$DIRNAME device pointing to
# $DIRNAME to /etc/fstab
```

You should do this in single user mode and reboot afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the Explanation. I was curios as /root can have these folders.
But from what I can read these are virtual volumes? could I create these too?

Comment: You can create any folder you want under `/root`, just as under your home directory.  Are you asking how to create separate logical volumes using LVM using the same volume group as the one storing `/home`?

Comment: Oh wow thank you for the additional informations and Explanation and your time, this really helps, but with a different problem I have.
Sorry for referencing them as virtual volumes, in Btrfs they are called subvolumes, I'm not sure how they are called in ZFS. /home /var etc are afaik actually subvolumes, so I thought if I can create them myself, I only need to find the config file where this link to the orignal subvolumes is stored. (or inside the partition table?) But as you sad, this could break more than it could be helpfull, so I'm not sure anymore if this is right way to go